# dev c++. Получить координаты курсора

Tags: c++

dev c++. Создать проект Windows Application. Получить координаты курсора через каждую 1 секунду и записать все результаты в текстовый файл.

Answer (score 5):

Для получения координат воспользуйтесь функцией [GetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390(VS.85).aspx)

```
POINT p;
if (GetCursorPos(&p))
{
    //позиция курсора: p.x  p.y
}
```

Так же вам пригодится [ScreenToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162952(VS.85).aspx) для маппинга координат в win координаты.

```
if (ScreenToClient(hwnd, &p))
{
    //p.x и p.y относительны вашего окна
}
```

Что бы периодически получать координаты, воспользуйтесь например таймером:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

void timer_start(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]() {
        while (true)
        {
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));
        }
    }).detach();
}


void do_something()
{
    std::cout << "I am doing something" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    timer_start(do_something, 1000);

    while(true);
}
```

Записать данные в файл можно следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open ("тест.txt");
  myfile << "Данные для записи.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ScreenToClient по условию задачи вряд ли нужен. Ну и если WinAPI, то почему бы не SetTimer или вообще Sleep в цикле?

Comment: Да можно и таймер со слипом :) Никто не запрещает.